# Detecting last character

Tags: java, arrays, string

Im trying to detect whether the last character of a string contains an operator using an array checker that was previously used for integers. For some reason the code will always display "Not In" Even if the last character is an operator

```
class Main {
    public static boolean useLoopString(String[] arr, String targetValue) 
    {
        for (String s : arr) {
            if (s == targetValue)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] op={"+","-","×","÷"};
        String eq = "43+4+";
        String eqLast=eq.substring(eq.length()-1);
        System.out.println(eqLast);
        boolean in=useLoopString(op,eqLast);
        if(in){
            System.out.println("In");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not In");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use char to compare, like this:

```
  public static boolean useLoopString(char[] arr, char targetValue) {
        for (char ch : arr) {
            if (ch == targetValue)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] op = { '+', '-', '×', '÷' };
        String eq = "43+4+";
        char eqLast = eq.charAt(eq.length() - 1);
        boolean in = useLoopString(op, eqLast);
        if (in) {
            System.out.println("In");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not In");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `==` on class objects checks whether the two objects are the exact same instance, rather than whether the objects are equivalent, as you are intending. Instead, you should use `.equals` as `String`s are classes:

```
public static boolean useLoopString(String[] arr, String targetValue) {
    for (String s : arr) {
        if (s.equals(targetValue))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Would this also apply for chars

Comment: @DanielTodd nope, `char`s are primitive values so you can compare them using `==`. The only exception would be if you created an instance of the wrapper `Character` class, rather than a `char`. In that case, you would have to compare the `Character` class objects using `.equals`

Answer (score 0):

String equality should be checked using the `equals` method. One should not use the object reference comparison.

In your case `s` and `targetValue` might be logically equal but may or may not point to the same `String` object.

Therefore, replace

`if (s == targetValue)`

with

`if (s.equals(targetValue))`

Also, null check should be made before making method calls on any object.

Answer (score 0):

typically in production world, Edge cases if array has null element,  you end up with null pointer exception.
always safe to use if(s!=null && s.equals(targetValue))
or 
use apache's StringUtils.equals(String a, Strin b)